# App crashes because of null object reference

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem when calling (user.getlat) and (user.getlng).
I have declared user object globally, and initialized it in the getUserData() method.

but when I run the app the app crashes and in the logcat is says:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double com.example.profile.User.getLat()' on a null object reference

```
public class Profile extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.child("users");
User user;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}

public void getUserData(){
    String uID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    myRef.child(uID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

            Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "" + user.lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Prints the value normally!

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Failed to read from database!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    LatLng userL = new LatLng(user.getLat(),user.getLng()); // The problem occurs here! 
    mMap.clear();
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userL).title("Your Location"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userL,17));

}
```

}

Comment: But how do you know that `onDataChange` gets called before `onMapReady`?

Comment: (Giving no scope to a variable in Java make the member to be package protected, not "globally declared".)

Comment: Sounds like your app is calling `onMapReady` before you actually set up your user in `getUserData`. At the very least you should be doing a null check before accessing your user data for safety

Comment: @StalemateOfTuning The code in getUserData method was in the onCreate method still the same problem.

Does onMapReady called before onCreate?

Comment: @SyfJO I have not used this API so I wouldn't know exactly when it gets called without reading the docs. I suspect it's asynchronous anyway, so probably not a good idea to make any assumptions one way or the other. Regardless, there isn't really a good reason *not* to null check your resources here, and from there maybe you can get a better idea of the flow through debugging.

Comment: @StalemateOfTuning When running the app the getUserDate method is invoked before the onMapReady method!

Comment: That doesn't mean that `onDataChange()` is running before `onMapReady()`. Firebase operations are _asynchronous_.

Comment: @MikeM. how to know if onDataChange() is running before onMapReady() ?

Comment: For testing? Put log prints in both methods, and see which prints first. Or, put breakpoints in both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you haven't called `getUserData()` method in anywhere. I read that you tried to add that logic in `onCreate()` too, but it didn't work.

Adding a listener doesn't mean that you will get what is expected of it, instantaneously.

Use the `onMapReady()` method only to set the map, with settings which is not dependent on `User`. Add/Modify the map marker only when you detect changes in the `User` data. See the changes:

```
public void getUserData(){
    String uID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    myRef.child(uID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            LatLng userL = new LatLng(user.getLat(),user.getLng());
            if(mMap!=null){
               mMap.clear();
               mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userL).title("Your 
               Location"));
             mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userL,17));
            }
            Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "" + user.lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Prints the value normally!

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Failed to read from database!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
}
```

Please call the method `getUserData()` or move its code in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer solved my problem :)
btw I called the getUserData() from the onCreate() method but I deleted it when I posted the question :P